# Ignore "document is not defined" error

Tags: node.js

The following line belongs to a 3rd party library I'm using in a Nodejs script:

```
if (document === undefined) return false;
```

[source](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/8399073fde8e242ef0a5beddcf165bc0c7fc84f0/src/pixi/utils/Utils.js#L33)

it is raising

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

I could get around it by wrapping the if statement in a try catch block:

```
try {
  if (document === undefined) return false;
} catch (e) {
  return false;
}
```

Is there another option that doesn't require modifying the library code?

Comment: Try `typeof document === 'undefined'`

Comment: Did you [read the users guide](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/master/README.md#browserify--cjs)?

Comment: @Amit, thanks. I didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hack but I guess you just set it before you call into the library.

```
console.log(document ===  undefined) //error

global.document = undefined
console.log(document ===  undefined) //true
```

Comment: Very smart hacky way haha. @Fabricator probably fork your own copy of the library, get rid of the buggy code and modify the relevant package.json  to pull from your copy. Meanwhile raise an issue, put in pull request and probably wait...